# Testing Ember.js route navigation from within a controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am attempting to write a test in my ember-cli application that tests whether a particular controller action will take the user to a specific route based on the value of an input on the page.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
IndexController: the setTable action navigates to the tables route
    ✘ Died on test #1     at http://localhost:7357/assets/qunit.js:425
        at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:72425)
        at :29
        at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:54
        at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:14: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'target.transitionToRoute')
```

If I attempt it in the browser this is the error I get in the console:

```
Error while loading route: undefined
```

My route is defined, here's my router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: AccelewaiterENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('table', { path: '/table/:table_id' });
});

export default Router;
```

Here's my test:

```
import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('controller:index', 'IndexController', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  // needs: ['controller:foo']
});

test('the setTable action navigates to the tables route', function() {
  var controller = this.subject();
  controller.set('tableNumber', 1);
  controller.send('setTable');
  ok(controller.get('currentPath') === '/table/1');
});
```

Here's my template:

```
<div class="start">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      {{input type="text"
        valueBinding="tableNumber"
        class="form-control input-lg"
        placeholder="Enter Table #"}}

      <button {{ action 'setTable' }}
         id="submit-table"
         class="btn btn-success">Ok</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  tableNumber: null,

  actions: {
    setTable: function() {
      var tableNumber = this.get('tableNumber');
      console.log(this.transitionTo);
      this.transitionToRoute('table/' + tableNumber);
    }
  }
});
```

I also have a table controller created, it's currently empty though.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`transitionTo` only exists on items extending `Ember.Route`.

For items extending `Ember.Controller`/`Ember.ObjectController`/`Ember.ArrayController` `transitionToRoute` should be used.

Additionally `currentPath` only exists on the `ApplicationController` and while integration testing.  It looks like you're mixing integration testing and unit testing.

With an Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipo/33/edit

Comment: I'm still getting the same in browser error when using 'transitionToRoute'. I'm also getting an error in my acceptance test when trying to use getController. Again, I'm using ember-cli here so is there some convention that should be followed there?

Comment: ember-cli just bundles up your ember app, it is essentially the same as the jsbin.  Can you try and reproduce with the jsbin I provided?

Comment: Well, in the jsbin you provided, when I add Ember as a library it is not finding "andThen". Did this bin work for you initially? It hasn't for me yet.